# Transform numpy array with image data to long format

Tags: python, image, numpy

I want to transform an image to "long format" and back. My code right now is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

img = mpimg.imread('/path/image.png')

image = []
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        image.append([i, j] + img[i, j].tolist())
image = np.array(image)
```

but I am sure there is a more efficient, but strangely could not find anything on the Internet. What is a faster solution?

The code above produces the correct result. My image is colored, so `img.shape` is a 3-tuple.

Comment: Is this a working code (one that gives expected output)? Also, is `img` a 2D (grayscale) or 3D (RGB) array?

Comment: @Divakar: I clarified this in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by `long format`?  Your  image as an array will be (n,m,3) shape.  What the result supposed to be?

Comment: @hpaulj: The result is supposed to look like the result that my code produces. My code should be a minimal working implementation. Does it it not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
m,n = img.shape[:2]
r,c = np.mgrid[:m,:n]
out = np.column_stack((r.ravel(), c.ravel(), img.reshape(-1,img.shape[2])))
```

Alternative to get `r,c` :

```
r,c = np.indices(img.shape[:2])
```

Another with array-assignment -

```
m,n,r = img.shape
out = np.empty((m,n,2+r), dtype=img.dtype)
out[:,:,0] = np.arange(m)[:,None]
out[:,:,1] = np.arange(n)
out[:,:,2:] = img
out = out.reshape(m*n,-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `np.indices`, transposing to match your loop and reshaping to get a 2D array.

```
ix = np.transpose(np.indices(img.shape[:2]), (1,2,0))
image = np.concatenate((ix, img), axis=2).reshape(-1, image.shape[2] + 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to get the timing:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

t0 = time.time()
image_orig = []
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        image_orig.append([i, j] + img[i, j].tolist())
image_orig = np.array(image_orig)
print(time.time() - t0)

t0 = time.time()
ix = np.transpose(np.indices(img.shape[:2]), (1,2,0))
image = np.concatenate((ix, img), axis=2).reshape(-1, img.shape[2] + 2)
print(time.time() - t0)

t0 = time.time()
m,n = img.shape[:2]
r,c = np.indices(img.shape[:2])
out = np.column_stack((r.ravel(), c.ravel(), img.reshape(-1,img.shape[2])))
print(time.time() - t0)

t0 = time.time()
m,n,r = img.shape
out = np.empty((m,n,2+r), dtype=img.dtype)
out[:,:,0] = np.arange(m)[:,None]
out[:,:,1] = np.arange(n)
out[:,:,2:] = img
out = out.reshape(m*n,-1)
print(time.time() - t0)
```

> 0.17211008071899414
>
> 0.001434326171875
>
> 0.0013523101806640625
>
> 0.0008423328399658203

The last variant seems to be the fastest.